# Why does Azure SQL server have multiple/different DNS entries

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am having timeout while using my Azure SQL Server DB from an Azure App Service all of a sudden. The error message is unclear so, out of idea, I ran Azure team's [connection check script](https://github.com/Azure/SQL-Connectivity-Checker).

It results in a warning message informing that my server with address

```
foobar.database.windows.net
```

has two different IP resolutions from two different DNS sources (IP addresses altered):

```
Found DNS record in DNS server (IP Address:40.78.240.8)
Found DNS record in Open DNS (IP Address:40.78.248.10)

WARNING: Distinct DNS records were found! (40.78.240.8, 40.78.248.10)
 While testing DNS resolution from multiples sources (hosts file/cache/your DNS server/external DNS service) we got multiple addresses.
 To connect to SQL Database or Azure Synapse, you need to allow network traffic to and from all Gateways for the region.
 The Gateway used is not static, configuring a single specific address (like in hosts file) may lead to total lack of connectivity or intermittent connectivity issues (now or in the f
uture).
 Having DNS resolution switching between a couple of Gateway addresses is expected.
 If you are using Private Link, a mismatch between your DNS server and OpenDNS is expected.
 Please review the DNS results.
```

These are [valid Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/gateway-ip-addresses) [gateways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql) IPs.

The warning message itself seems to indicate these are just gateways/proxies so having multiple is not a problem. But it is also a *Warning* and does not happen on my other Azure Sql instances.

What does that mean and is it an actual issue or is it expected?